# leaflet R popup suddenly changed output?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I´m working on a leaflet map in r that visualizes data from a survey onto the map. You can get a look of how it looked over here: https://maglin.shinyapps.io/UM33/ . As you can see if you click on an area you get the name of thea area and the median score on the various questions in Swedish, for example this...

```
>! Område: Eds Glesbygd
Fler kultur­ och fritidsaktiviteter för äldre : 7.9
Fler kultur­ och fritidsaktiviteter för barn och ungdomar : 8.7
Förbättra äldreomsorgen i kommunen : 8.9
Fler ungdomsgårdar och fältassistenter : 9
Minska barngrupperna i förskolan : 9.9
```

But after some changes in the program I get this instead...

```
>!Område: 1:43 
Bevara existerande större grönområden : c(5, 9.4, 9.6, 10.4, 8.7, 10.8, 8, 9.8, 7.3, 9.7, 12, 9, 10.1, 9.3, 9.4, 9.7, 8.5, 9.7, 10, 1, 8.4, 9.1, 10.2, 6.2, 8, 10.1, 11.5, 10.8, 9.7, 8.7, 10.3, 9.6, 10.6, 10.9, 10.9, 10, 10.7, 8, 9.4, 10.9, 6, 9.6, 14) 
Anlägga parker i existerande stadsdelar : c(8, 8.1, 9.1, 9.4, 7.1, 9.6, 7.8, 9.4, 7.2, 7.4, 9, 8.2, 6.7, 8.4, 9, 9, 8.6, 8, 8, 3, 7.8, 7.8, 8, 5.2, 6.7, 8.1, 8.2, 8.9, 7.5, 7.3, 8.8, 7.7, 7.8, 7.5, 7.8, 10, 8.2, 5.7, 7.8, 7, 8, 8.2, 7) 
Bygga bostäder nära grönområden : c(11, 7.7, 8.3, 6.9, 7.3, 6.6, 5.2, 7.6, 8.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.4, 7.5, 8.7, 7.3, 11.3, 8.2, 8, 9, 13, 6.8, 6.7, 8, 9.2, 11, 7.2, 5.8, 7.5, 6.3, 8.3, 7.6, 8.1, 8.4, 9.1, 7.5, 13, 7.3, 11, 8.6, 5.9, 9, 7.3, 7) 
Rusta upp befintliga parker : c(6, 9.4, 9.6, 10.7, 8.1, 9.9, 8.8, 8.8, 6.9, 9.5, 9, 9.1, 9.9, 8.3, 8.9, 11, 9.9, 9.7, 6, 12, 8.8, 9.4, 9.3, 9.5, 10, 9, 8.9, 9.6, 9.6, 8.5, 9.2, 8.5, 9.2, 9.3, 9, 14, 9.9, 9.7, 9.3, 10.3, 6, 9.7, 7) 
Skapa bättre tillgänglighet till större grönområden : c(7, 8.1, 8.7, 9.2, 8.1, 9.1, 7.4, 8.5, 8.5, 8, 9.5, 7.2, 8.6, 7.6, 7.9, 8, 7, 8.7, 9, 13, 7.2, 7.3, 9, 6.2, 8.3, 8.5, 8.4, 9.1, 8.2, 7, 8.9, 8.2, 7.8, 7.8, 8, 13, 8.7, 9, 8.2, 8.4, 8, 8.3, 7)
```

The popup seems to show all the medians for every area instead of just the one you clicked on. This is an example of how the data looks when I save it inside an reactive variable...

```
                     Area   X1a   X1b   X1c   X1d   X1e favorit
                   (fctr) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)   (chr)
1        Antuna /Älvsunda   5.0   8.0  11.0   6.0   7.0     X1c
2             Brunnby/Vik   9.4   8.1   7.7   9.4   8.1     X1a
3  Carlslund/Brunnby Park   9.6   9.1   8.3   9.6   8.7     X1a
4             Dragonvägen  10.4   9.4   6.9  10.7   9.2     X1d
5            Eds Glesbygd   8.7   7.1   7.3   8.1   8.1     X1a
```

And this is how the data looks when I print it out just before it gets feed into the addPolygons(popup) function...

```
>!"<Strong>Område: </strong> 1:43 <br><Strong> Bevara existerande större grönområden :</strong> c(5, 9.4, 9.6, 10.4, 8.7, 10.8, 8, 9.8, 7.3, 9.7, 12, 9, 10.1, 9.3, 9.4, 9.7, 8.5, 9.7, 10, 1, 8.4, 9.1, 10.2, 6.2, 8, 10.1, 11.5, 10.8, 9.7, 8.7, 10.3, 9.6, 10.6, 10.9, 10.9, 10, 10.7, 8, 9.4, 10.9, 6, 9.6, 14) <br><strong> Anlägga parker i existerande stadsdelar :</strong> c(8, 8.1, 9.1, 9.4, 7.1, 9.6, 7.8, 9.4, 7.2, 7.4, 9, 8.2, 6.7, 8.4, 9, 9, 8.6, 8, 8, 3, 7.8, 7.8, 8, 5.2, 6.7, 8.1, 8.2, 8.9, 7.5, 7.3, 8.8, 7.7, 7.8, 7.5, 7.8, 10, 8.2, 5.7, 7.8, 7, 8, 8.2, 7) <br><strong> Bygga bostäder nära grönområden :</strong> c(11, 7.7, 8.3, 6.9, 7.3, 6.6, 5.2, 7.6, 8.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.4, 7.5, 8.7, 7.3, 11.3, 8.2, 8, 9, 13, 6.8, 6.7, 8, 9.2, 11, 7.2, 5.8, 7.5, 6.3, 8.3, 7.6, 8.1, 8.4, 9.1, 7.5, 13, 7.3, 11, 8.6, 5.9, 9, 7.3, 7) <br><strong> Rusta upp befintliga parker :</strong> c(6, 9.4, 9.6, 10.7, 8.1, 9.9, 8.8, 8.8, 6.9, 9.5, 9, 9.1, 9.9, 8.3, 8.9, 11, 9.9, 9.7, 6, 12, 8.8, 9.4, 9.3, 9.5, 10, 9, 8.9, 9.6, 9.6, 8.5, 9.2, 8.5, 9.2, 9.3, 9, 14, 9.9, 9.7, 9.3, 10.3, 6, 9.7, 7) <br><strong> Skapa bättre tillgänglighet till större grönområden :</strong> c(7, 8.1, 8.7, 9.2, 8.1, 9.1, 7.4, 8.5, 8.5, 8, 9.5, 7.2, 8.6, 7.6, 7.9, 8, 7, 8.7, 9, 13, 7.2, 7.3, 9, 6.2, 8.3, 8.5, 8.4, 9.1, 8.2, 7, 8.9, 8.2, 7.8, 7.8, 8, 13, 8.7, 9, 8.2, 8.4, 8, 8.3, 7)"
```

Has the dataset been turned into a factor or something? I can supply more code if needed, but I didn´t want to spam the OP with to much, The spoiler functions is messing with me.

**EDIT1**: So I have setup a project based on an old version that works and started looking for differences between the two projects. One difference so far is that there is a slight difference in the variable that is used to build the popup output...

In my current(faulty) project, this is what you get when you print out the variable

```
>print(var)
Source: local data frame [43 x 7]

                         Area   X1a   X1b   X1c   X1d   X1e favorit
                       (fctr) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)   (chr)
    1        Antuna /Älvsunda     5     8    11     6     7     X1c
    2             Brunnby/Vik     9     8     8     9     8     X1a
    3  Carlslund/Brunnby Park    10     9     8    10     9     X1a
    4             Dragonvägen    10     9     7    11     9     X1d
    5            Eds Glesbygd     9     7     7     8     8     X1a
    ..                    ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...     ...
```

In the older but working version the variable looks like this...

```
>print(var)
                             Area X1a X1b X1c X1d X1e favorit
1                Antuna /Älvsunda   5   8  11   6   7     X1c
2                     Brunnby/Vik   9   8   8   9   8     X1a
3          Carlslund/Brunnby Park  10   9   8  10   9     X1a
4                     Dragonvägen  10   9   7  11   9     X1d
5                    Eds Glesbygd   9   7   7   8   8     X1a
```

Have I accidentally changed a file/object type here that makes scrambles things up?

**Edit2**: I seem to have solved the problem by saving the dataset that (var) reads from in .csv format and then reading it in again, Any got a clue why that works?

**Edit3**: Seems the change happens when I call the plyr rename function, that seems to garble the output.

Comment: Are you using version control? Git maybe? Can you tell us what changes you made and post those snippets at least.

Comment: I use git but I rarely update it and I haven´t pulled from it in a long while. No version control. I was working on implementing checkboxes that let you subset the output based on data the survey supplied(gender, age, occupation...), I have tried to backtrack my steps and comment away all new code but problem remains, gonna update the OP with some snippets that might shine some light on it.

Comment: Well, let this be a lesson then. Shiny is not the most robust platform I have ever worked on.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem when I click on a region of the map I get the good popup. what changes did you do?

Comment: I made some changes after I deployed the app on shinyapps, which seems to have resulted in the new output in the popups. 
I was mainly trying out if-clauses to a group of checkboxes, but I have commented out all changes I have made and the problem remains, Gonna have to look more upon it tomorrow.

Comment: is `var` created using a `dplyr` chain?

Comment: Why are there big vectors in the string you're feeding to `popup`? Just `paste` together any html/text with an expression for the variable, e.g. `popup = paste('<strong>Variable 1:</strong>', data$var1)`

Comment: I have no dplyr functions in my chain but I have used functions from dplyr to manipulate the dataset the var variable draws from. Also I seem to have solved the problem by saving the dataset that the var variable uses as a csv file and then reading it in again.

Comment: @alistaire You seem to have misunderstood me, I actually do something similar to that, see the following snippet:.....

område_popup <-paste( "<Strong>Område: </strong>",
                          Variable1[,1],
                          "<br><Strong>",Variable2[1,],":</strong>",
                          Variable1[,2],

Comment: Are you pulling the variables for the popup from the same data structure as your polygons? (Something like `shapefile@data$var1` for each?) Otherwise indexing might be off, or data out of date.

Comment: The difference between the two dataframes in Edit 1 is class. The first was at some point a result of a `dplyr` function, and so now has classes for `tbl_df` and `tbl` as well as `data.frame` (the second only `data.frame`). The class really shouldn't make any difference, though; they subset exactly the same. The `dplyr` call may be making the actual data dissimilar, though.

Comment: @Alistaire Unfortunately the class change seems to effect the output as I cant see any difference in the data between the two different versions. I have changed my code so I dont need rename(), but I still need "group_by(Area) %>%summarise_each(funs(mean))" is there a way to reverse the class change after the function or get the same result without using group_by()summarise_each?

Comment: You can technically do everything in `dplyr` in base R; it's just a bigger pain. Try `class(yourDataFrame) <- 'data.frame'` to revert, although I still don't understand why it's causing problems.

Comment: @alistaire That solved the problem! Now I get the proper popup output and get to keep dplyr functions, Thanks :p

Comment: at the end of your `dplyr` chain you can also have `%>% as.data.frame`. Also, it's a good idea to use `%>% ungroup` after you've used the grouped data.